# Averaging Models in Excel

Tags: analysis, mathematical-modeling, average, data-analysis, means

I am working in Excel and have two sets of data points that come up with a percentage for the likelihood of a recession. I am wondering what the best strategy would be to combine these data points? Should I just average them, use the geometric mean, harmonic mean, or is there another method someone would suggest? Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe whichever number you are more confident in should get a higher weight. Otherwise: principle of insufficient reason, same weight.